# How to convert UTF8 hex to Unicode codepoint in python

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, iconv, emoji

I'm making a config file that contains the map of emoji's Unicode and SoftBank Unicode. Now I'm using a python program to scrach this information from http://punchdrunker.github.com/iOSEmoji/table_html/ios6/index.html

but there is a problem , the SoftBank Code on the web page is UTF8 hex, not Unicode codepoint , how to change it to Unicode codePoint?

for example , I want to change EE9095 to E415  (the first emoji emotion)

I try  to do it like this , but it just didn't work

```
code.decode('utf-8')
```

but it just didn't work, the code is the same, didn't change.
the unix command iconv didn't work too

Comment: Please add an example of the "UTF8 hex" string to the question.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure `code` is actually encoded in UTF-8? This works for me:

```
>>> b'\xee\x90\x95'.decode('utf-8')
u'\ue415'
```

Comment: I scrached code form the webpage, is it be encoded already?, I do it like this     code='ee9095'   code.decode('utf-8')

Comment: @user1462782: `'ee9095'` will be a string of 6 bytes ('e', 'e', '9', '0', '9', '5'). This is different from `'\xee\x90\x95'` which is a string of 3 bytes (0xee, 0x90, 0x95). You need to convert the hex string `'ee9095'` to an actual byte sequence using e.g. `bytearray.fromhex('ee9095').decode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
>>> 'EE9095'.decode('hex').decode('utf-8')
<<< u'\ue415'
```

Comment: Python 3: `bytes.fromhex('EE9095').decode('utf-8')` -> 
`'\ue415'`